# Window 2003 server SP2 detection

Tags: windows, version, installshield

Is it possible to automatically detect if Window Server 2003 has SP2 installed?

I'm working in InstallShield 9 install script, so I suppose I need to check some registry key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used InstallShield since 2003 or so I'm not sure what will be available but check out:

http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield14langref/LangrefSYSINFO.htm

Check out

SYSINFO.nISOSL == ISOSL_WINSERVER2003
SYSINFO.WINNT.bWinServer2003 
SYSINFO.WINNT.nServicePack

```
 if (SYSINFO.WINNT.bWinServer2003 && SYSINFO.WINNT.nServicePack > 1 ) then 

    MessageBox("Server 2003 SP2 or Greater Detected",INFORMATION); 

endif;
```

Comment: BTW, I meant I have used InstallShield "9" since 2003. :-)